# Could Reinhardt cardinals could exist even if all cardinals below it were well-orderable?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, large-cardinals

Are there axioms intermediate in strength between the axiom of dependent choice and the full axiom of choice?

Is it possible for ZFC to be the inner model of a theory where in the outer model, choice fails?

I ask because I'm wondering if Reinhardt cardinals could exist even if the reals and many large cardinals were well-orderable.

If this is possible, would it have any problematic consequences like the axiom of determinacy is said to?

If not, why not?

Comment: The title seems to be a different question than any of the four or so mentioned in the body of your post.  I'd suggest editing to focus on the first problem more clearly, or perhaps tying these problems together in a more compelling way, if the thread running through them is the motivation.

Comment: Fair enough, done. I did get an informative answer out of the former title question however, in addition to the other questions, so it was useful enough I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of an infinite Dedekind-finite set is consistent with ZF and contradicts both choice (in fact, even *countable* choice!) and determinacy. AC versus AD isn't a dichotomy by any means, there are *lots* of other ways things could go. Another more technical example: the existence of an amorphous set contradicts the existence of infinite Dedekind-finite sets + the *non*existence of incomparable Dedekind-finite sets, and both of these principles contradict both AC and AD and are consistent with ZF (okay, in the second case assuming an inaccessible exists; [it isn't known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172329/does-sageevs-result-need-an-inaccessible) if that's necessary yet).

The question of axioms between DC and AC isn't directly related, but yes, there are intermediate axioms: e.g. DC + "AC holds for all sets of size $<\beth_{\omega^2+17}$." (Incidentally, ZF+AD does *not* prove DC; this is due to Solovay. However, [ZF+AD+$V=L(\mathbb{R})$ does imply DC](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/38675/). It is open whether ZF+AD proves DC$(\omega^\omega)$.)

---

Re: your second paragraph, you're confusing *models* and *theories* a bit, but: every model $M$ of ZF has an inner model satisfying ZFC, namely $L^M$. This inner model also satisfies a bunch of other principles, including the generalized continuum hypothesis. This goes the other way too: models of ZFC can have (but don't always have) inner models in which choice fails. For example, the most well-known class of determinacy models is the class of models of the form $L(\mathbb{R})^M$ where $M$ is a model of ZFC + enough large cardinals (if I recall correctly, a proper class of Woodins).

Now you ask specifically about Reinhardts and well-orderings of "small" sets (like $\mathbb{R}$). Well, the usual way to do this would be to argue that forcing $\mathbb{R}$ to be well-orderable can be done with a forcing which is "small" with respect to the Reinhardt and then argue that small forcings preserve Reinhardt-ness. The first is clearly true, but the second I'm not sure about; forcing preservation results often need choice. I suspect that ZF + "There is a Reinhardt" is known to be equiconsistent with ZF + "There is a Reinhardt" + "$\mathbb{R}$ is well-orderable," but I'm not sure.

Comment: Very informative, thanks. Could Reinhardt cardinals exist even if all cardinals below it were well-orderable? I was wondering this specifically, but didn't ask.

Comment: @Embiggening What exactly do you mean - all sets of lower rank are well-orderable? (The only cardinalities "below" a well-ordered cardinality in the usual sense are well-ordered, and a Reinhardt cardinal is a well-orderable cardinal ...)

Comment: "(The only cardinalities "below" a well-ordered cardinality in the usual sense are well-ordered, and a Reinhardt cardinal is a well-orderable cardinal ...) " Huh, did not know that. I assumed that them being inconsistent with the axiom of choice meant they were not well-orderable. Obviously I was wrong then. "What exactly do you mean - all sets of lower rank are well-orderable?" Yes, I meant this.

Comment: @Embiggening Well, if $A$ injects into $B$ via $f$ and $B$ is well-ordered by $\trianglelefteq$, then consider the relation on $A$ gotten by "pulling back" $\trianglelefteq$ along $f^{-1}$; this well-orders $A$. *(Exercise: show that it's enough to assume the a priori weaker claim that $B$ surjects onto $A$.)* When we say that a Reinhardt cardinal is inconsistent with choice, we mean that if $M$ is a model of ZF, $\kappa\in M$, and $M\models$"$\kappa$ is a Reinhardt cardinal," then there is *some* set in $M$ which is not well-orderable in $M$. But this set won't itself be $\kappa$.

Comment: I see, so the answer to that question would be "no", if I'm understanding you correctly. So the axiom of choice failing at some point doesn't mean there's a sharp cutoff point after which no sets can be well-ordered. Interesting.

Comment: @Embiggening No - given any set $A$, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ which $A$ doesn't surject onto.

Comment: It is expected that Reinhardt cardinals are consistent with vast amounts of choice, just shy of what we know would lead to inconsistency by allowing us to run Kunen's theorem.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Is that expectation universal? I thought that Woodin at one point made some conjectures that would imply the inconsistency of ZF + Reinhardt, though I could have that backwards or be thinking of the wrong person.

Comment: It is one of those things. We do not really have enough evidence either way. But there are theorems (by Woodin) showing how to add vast amounts of choice via forcing starting with strengthenings of Reinhardt. How plausible are these strengthenings, or the assumption of Reinhardt cardinals itself is tricky. Woodin has recently been discussing some dichotomy theorems and several related questions whose resolution would either show that Reinhardt cardinals or "mild" strengthenings are inconsistent or, on the contrary, would lead to vast hierarchies beyond choice.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo That's interesting - is there a good source on those theorems? (And I presume those forcings preserve at least some of the Reinhardtiness involved.)

Comment: @Noah "Suitable extender models. I" has some related results, see for example Theorem 226.